# AWS Rekognition Client - Compare Faces

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sdk

I'm trying to use AWS Rekognition Client (SDK) in Javascript. I want to compared two faces using JPEG images sending the following request:

{SimilarityThreshold: 70, SourceImage: {,…}, TargetImage: {,…}}
SimilarityThreshold: 70,
SourceImage: {
Bytes: "dataimage/jpegbase64/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4
},
TargetImage: {
Bytes: "dataimage/jpegbase64/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2
}

Each Image I send as Uint8Array after check the type on github but I received the following error:

InvalidImageFormatException: Request has invalid image format
at de_InvalidImageFormatExceptionRes (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-rekognition/dist-es/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:4384:23)
at de_CompareFacesCommandError (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-rekognition/dist-es/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:679:25)
at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-es/deserializerMiddleware.js:8:24)
at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-es/awsAuthMiddleware.js:20:20)
at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-es/retryMiddleware.js:36:46)
at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-es/loggerMiddleware.js:9:26)
at async magia (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/page.js:91:30)

Is the correct format Uint8Array? I tested using base64 and I got the same error.

I will appreciate your feedback